# Circular dependency dropped: make, fortran and c building static library

Tags: c, makefile, fortran

I am trying to build a static library with mixed c and fortran code. When building the fortran files, I receive this error for each of my fortran files, but not the c files.

```
make: Circular file0.F90 <- file0.F90.o dependency dropped.
mpif90 -c -O2 -o "file0.F90.o" "file0.F90"
```

The Makefile I am using is below. My rule for F90 files is the same as for c files, so I am not sure why it should have this behaviour?

```
CC = mpicc
FC = mpif90

TARGET=libpxn   
FCFLAGS    = -O2 -fPIC
CFLAGS     = -O2 -fPIC -lm -Wall
CPPFLAGS   = $(CFLAGS)

SRCS = $(wildcard *.F90) $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS =  $(patsubst %, %.o, $(SRCS)) 

# Rules
all: static

static: $(OBJS) 
    ar rcs $(TARGET).a  $(OBJS)

%.c.o: %.c 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"

%.F90.o: %.F90
    $(FC) -c $(FCFLAGS) -o "$@" "$<"

clean: 
    @printf "Cleaning: \n"
    @find . -type f -name '*.o' -print0 | xargs -0 -I % sh -c 'printf "% "; rm -f %'
    rm -f $(TARGET).so $(TARGET).a
```

I tried also with gnu compilers with the same result. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.c` is a built-in suffix, meaning at the very least there is one built-in rule defined as `%.c:` which will stop make from applying match anything rules (`%:`) to files ending with `.c`.

Make has no idea about `.F90` on the other hand, so when it reaches the prerequisites of your `%.F90.o` rule, it will try to apply the match anything rule `%: %.o` which results in `file0.F90: file0.F90.o`, and a circular dependency.

The quick and dirty solution is to simply add an empty pattern rule for `.F90`

```
%.F90:
```

---

The "correct" way (IMHO) to handle this would be to rewrite your makefile to conform to the built-in implicit rules

```
TARGET  := libpxn.a
CC      := mpicc
FC      := mpif90
FFLAGS  := -O2 -fPIC
CFLAGS  := -O2 -fPIC -Wall
ARFLAGS := rcs

CSRCS := $(wildcard *.c)
FSRCS := $(wildcard *.F90)
OBJS  := $(CSRCS:.c=.o) $(FSRCS:.F90=.o)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)($(OBJS))

%.o: %.F90
    $(COMPILE.F) $(OUPUT_OPTION) $<

%.F90:

clean: 
    $(info "Cleaning:")
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

Make has a built-in rule for archives so you can just specify `ARFLAGS` and use  `libname(objects)` as a prerequisite (IIRC if you're using GNU `ar` you don't need `s` as it'll always make an index).

The `F90` recipe is copied from make's built-in rule for `.F`, in fact if you use `.F` as a fortran suffix instead of `.F90` you won't even need this rule.

If you have two source files with the same stem (say `foo.c` and `foo.F90`) you'll either have to split the sources into two subdirectories (recommended), or go back to your original plan of the double suffix (you'll need to provide both rules again in that case).

I've rewritten `clean` as the objects are intermediate files now and will be deleted automatically after they are added to the archive.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a non 'quick and dirty' solution to this?

Comment: @timofiend I thought you'd never ask :D I can't right now but I'll post an update in about 8 hours or so. It's mostly just about fixing a couple of quirks in your current setup.

Comment: @timofiend Updated

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats really helpful - in particular I didnt know the built in rule for archives, everythings made a lot simpler. If I could upvote a second time I would!

Comment: @timofiend No worries, the trick with make is adapt your build to make's conventions as much as possible rather than the other way round.